# How to split a String with two delimiters and keep only one of of them?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I want to split a String in punctuation marks and white spaces, but keep the punctuation marks. E.x

```
String example = "How are you? I am fine!"
```

I want to have as a result

```
["How","are","you","?","I","am","fine","!"]
```

but instead I get

```
["how"," ","are"," ","you"," ","?"," ","i"," ","am"," ","fine"," ","!"].
```

what I used was  `example.toLowerCase().trim().split("(?<=\\b|[^\\p{L}])");`

Comment: Why are you doing `toLowerCase()`? This already messes up your expected result. And why the `trim()`? Also, you could simply iterate your resulting array and get rid of everything that `isBlank()`. Or do you need it to be done with a single `split` call?

Comment: @Zabuzard toLowerCase is not that nessecary, and how exactly is it messing the results?! I tried with and without it and I still got the same result! I tried iterating through the array and get rid of all the unused space but I still didnt get the result I wanted, so therefore I would rather do it in a single split call or using the Stringtokenizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing `toLowerCase()`? This already messes up your expected result. And why the `trim()` on the full string?

Doing this with a single `split` call is probably not too simple.

An alternative would be to just filter out the unwanted entries:

```
String example = "How are you? I am fine!";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b");
String[] result = pattern.splitAsStream(example)
    .filter(Predicate.not(String::isBlank))
    .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Output:

```
[How, are, you, ? , I, am, fine, !]
```

---

Reacting to your comment of wanting `[How,are,you,?,I,am,fine,!]` as output; simply dont print with `Arrays.toString` but build the string yourself manually. The array does not contain any whitespaces.

```
System.out.println("[" + String.join(",", result) + "]");
```

Comment: this is almost exactly what I needed. I just need to get rid of the white spaces in the strings in the output string too [How,are,you,?,I,am,fine,!]

Comment: Then dont print with `Arrays.toString`. The array itself doesnt contain any whitespaces. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "How are you? I am fine!";
        String[] arr = example.split("\\s+|\\b(?=\\p{Punct})");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[How, are, you, ?, I, am, fine, !]
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `\\s+` specifies the space
2. `\\b` specifies the word boundary
3. `(?=\\p{Punct})` specifies the positive look ahead for punctuation.
4. `|` specifies the alternation (`OR`)